# es importante arreglar estas advertencias?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Buenas soy algo nuevo en angular y por primera vez estoy enfrentando un problema con el NPM install
empecé teniendo problemas con un modulo y encontré que la respuesta era revisar si tenía dicho paquete instalado, al ejecutar la linea de comando npm list -g npm, me encuentro con que está vacía.
Al momento de hacer el npm install me lanza una serie de advertencias
(Adjuntaré foto con las advertencias)[image: WARM npm]

Logré arreglar el primer npm pero el resto no se si deba solucionarlos o no... con jasmine me tira errrores.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, @JaimeWrighton, usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/470526/edit) para añadir tu error en formato de texto; es mucho mejor si pegas el error acá a que lo pongas en imagen. Algunos usuarios tienen problemas para leer las imágenes adjuntas, como se puede caer el servidor que las almacena; por lo que es mucho mejor poner la información en texto acá para asegurar que la información se preserve.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario arreglarlo.
Son sólo advertencias, sugerencias que te da la consola, pero mientras no sea un error y veas que funciona, no necesitas meterle mano.